# JBoss Data Virtualization setting

Tags: jboss

I am trying to change the JBoss Data Virtualization settings of my server to increase the performance.I am working on the cache consideration properties. I have noticed that with this attribute

```
    "preparedplan-cache-infinispan-container" => "teiid-cache",

    "resultset-cache-infinispan-container" => "teiid-cache",
```

the value can either be teiid or teiid-cache.. I would like to know the difference and how it would affect the performance of the server.
Also would like to have suggestions on how i can increase the performance of the server.

Answer (score 0):

This option is simply pointing to the infinispan cache container settings in the JBoss EAP. So in this case "teiid" is just pointing another configuration setting. These typically deal with expiration of cache, eviction and number entries as such.

Overall resultset caching can improve your performance, however the above settings only let you configure how manage those cache container settings. Look under "infinispan" subsystem in standalone-teiid.xml file to find the configuration for "teiid". BTW, there is no "teid-cache" any more.